# 'text-justify' Worked Differently In Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, text-justify

I was working with my website with bootstrap and found out that the justified part of my text was shown differently in Chrome and Firefox.

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12 float1" style="background-color: #666;">
  <div>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 0">The intention to build is often clouded with difficult planning that involves multiple parties which is hard to be coordinated. SAM is here as your one-stop-solution. Engineering, designing, procuring, managing, building, and finishing. Sit back and
      relax as we handle your dreamed project - We do it all.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.float1 {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

My goal is to make the text appear exactly the same.

Pictures:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoozs.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WB4H.jpg

Comment: I am facing the same issue.